# Conditional require file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, uglifyjs, tree-shaking

I want to bundle the files into my production build only if it is not for `DEBUG`;

So I've use `webpack.DefinePlugin` and set the variable `DEBUG === true`.

Also config `webpack.UglifyJsPlugin` with default options

And in the js file, I do like this:

```
const A = DEBUG === true ? null : require('./some-debug.js');
//do things with A, for example
console.log(A)
```

I checked the final bundle file, A is replaced with null (so `DefinePlugin` is working fine), but the content of `some-debug.js` file is still in the bundle js.

Is it possible to let webpack not require the file?

ps: 
I think I can use `resolve.alias` to resolve `'./some-debug.js' --> undefined`. But I want to keep my webpack.config.js generic, dont' want to apply too many `resolve.alias` entries.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work with ternary operator.

```
let A;  
if (DEBUG === true) {
  A = require('./some-debug.js');
}
```